# How do I change the column name in a reactive data frame?

Tags: r, shiny

I am calling the following function:

```
output$table1 <- renderTable({
    data.frame(apply(dataSource1(), 2, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))

    })
```

and it is producing a table with the column name: `apply(dataSource1(), 2, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE)` as shown in the photo below:
[image]

How do I rename the column to not show the function call as the column name?  I want to rename it to "Value" or something along those lines.

When I try:

```
output$table1 <- renderTable({
    table_1 <- data.frame(apply(dataSource1(), 2, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
    colnames(table_1) <- c("", "Value")
    })
```

I get the error:
`names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]`

Comment: `data.frame(Value=apply(...))` or `names(table_1) <- "Value"`, you have but one column

Comment: I receive error: `no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: surely you tried `colnames(table_1) <- c("Value")`

Comment: I got the error: `no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: As @TheTime hints at, it looks like your table only has one column. The units appear to be row names. So the vector of names you assign should only have a length of 1.

Comment: @TheTime was actually correct in their first response.  I had `as.data.frame` instead of `data.frame` in my code.  Doing `data.frame(Value=apply(...))` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Shiny is only recognizing one colname in your function colnames(table_1) <- c("","Value") and trying to assign it to two columns.

Try adding a name in your first column such as

colnames(table_1) <- c("Units","Value")

Comment: `colnames(table_1) <- c("Value")` returns the error:  no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "character" and `colnames(table_1) <- c("Units", "Value")` returns the error: `'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]`

Answer (score 0):

`data.frame(Value=apply(...))` solved the problem!

```
output$table1 <- renderTable({
    data.frame(Value=apply(dataSource1(), 2, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))

    })
```